# How to access HttpRuntime.Cache in another project in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, caching

I have two projects [Main Project, Data Access Project] in one solution [`LDM`].

Main Project Contains Pages, scripts, images, etc.

Data Access Project Contains only Data Base operations.

I need to access `HttpRuntime.Cache` in Data Access Project.

How can i do that??

Comment: Your data access layer should never be aware of HttpRuntime.Cache. If so, your architecture is totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `HttpRuntime.Cache` to DAL `class` where you want to access. You can pass it as a parameter to constructor of method.

```
void SomeMethodInDal(HttpRuntime.Cache httpRuntimeCache)
{

}
```

It you be better to pass the required information from `HttpRuntime.Cache` to DAL instead of passing the `HttpRuntime.Cache`

Comment: Isn't there is another way to access HttpRuntime.Cache without passing  it as a parameter?

Comment: Actually Constructor of DAL Class Doesn't See HttpRuntime.Cache, So it can't accept it

Comment: You can pass the required information in some property before you want to use it. It would be better to use the required part instead of passing HttpRuntime.Cache

Answer (score 0):

You should wonder why do you want to use the Asp.Net cache in your DAL. In fact, the layers are because you want to distinguish between user interface and data access to keep low coupling in your code. If you just need the DAL access to a cache, define in the DAL a cache common interface:

```
public interface ICache {
   Object GetItem(String key);
   void SetItem(String key, Object item);
}
```

Then, in the presentation layer, create an implementation:

```
public class PlCache : ICache {
   public Object GetItem(String key) {
     return HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key);

   }

   public void SetItem(String key, Object item) {
      // TODO: you insert code
   }
}
```

Finally, in the DAL, you can use:

```
void DoSomething(ICache cache)
{

}
```

That, from the PL you can call `DoSomething(new PlCache())`;

---

Instead, **if in your DAL you just need any cache implementation**, you can use [System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I tried to use System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache but System.Runtime doesn't contain Caching Namespace in DataAccess Project

Comment: Ok i added that reference.
Can i Access 'Tests' Property in HttpRuntime.Cache Now?
Like That: HttpRuntime.Cache["Tests"]???

Comment: I read it "if in your DAL you just need any cache implementation, you can use System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache."
But how will i access the property in HttpRuntime.Cache?

Comment: you can write: System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default["Tests"]